# How should the app project depend on libHello.a and libHello.a depend on libPods.a?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I tried to use **cocoapods** in an static library project **iKit**, and use **iKit as a subproject** in my main app project. When I build the main app project, an **error** is occur:

Look image here: 
[image]

How should I struct the source and static library like that?

If I **directly** Use the cocoapods in main app project **TestiKit**, everything will be OK.

What I should do?

Answer (score 1):

If iKit has dependencies that are served from CocoaPods, they are definitely not being linked when you include the project this way. You'd probably be best off creating a podspec for iKit and linking that within your main project. Then in this new podspec you could specify iKit's dependencies and everything would be linked correctly. The issue here is that since you're not including the Pods project created in the iKit workspaces that CocoaPods uses Pods.xcconfig can't link its dependencies.